# Using a FireBreath plugin from vba

Tags: firebreath

I created a JSAPI plugin that work in the browser but since the Firebreath plugin is an activex, i would like to know if it is possible to use the same plugin from VBA.
The problem is that it crash on instantiation. I suspect some browser requirement, is it possible to work around ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote firebreath, and I have no idea.  I'm sure there is some way to make it work by tweaking the right things in the c++ activex code, but to my knowledge nobody has done what you're attempting.